# Getting Error 405 in POST and 404 in GET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

I have a MVC4 WebApi project working in dev environment, but got error when deploy to production.
I got httperror 405 when doing a POST, and 404 error when doing GET.  I know that the problem is my route is served by the wrong module, but could not figure out what is wrong.

Here is the failed request log for POST

```
ModuleName DirectoryListingModule 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 405 
HttpReason Method Not Allowed 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942401 
ConfigExceptionInfo 
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode Incorrect function. (0x80070001)
```

Here is the failed request log for GET

```
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification 16 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)
```

I have tried many solutions on the board, but none of them fix my issue.
My environment is Server 2008 R2, IIS7, I reinstalled .Net 4.0 framework, MVC 4. There is no WEBDAV installed, I have  in web.config. 
I had made sure that the appPool running in intergated mode under .net 4.0  I also made sure that all windows updates are installed.

Any idea what else I could try?  Appreciate very much.

Comment: something wrong in my original post. I have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in web.config

Comment: I solved this issue by changing my POST action in my controller to accept a complex object with the appropriate parameters as properties instead of a value types as method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

User words-like-jared provided in his comment the answer that solved this problem for me. This problem caused me hours of pain and trying several other dead ends. To help others find this solution easily, I am adding this answer so skimmers don't overlook it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once but it got solved when we changed the appPool to be ran under Classic mode.

It was NOT the exact same problem as you since we did not try a POST, but we did get the 404 error when performing GETs.